# I want to use a CQWP to show the list’s name description, any ideas?

Tags: web-part, xslt, xml

I’ve been going around in circles a bit with some XSL (as it seems easy to do) and I was wondering if you have a quick fix for this too.

I want to use a CQWP to show the list’s name and description at the top, then followed by all of the elements.  I’ve got the code below in a separate file to link to and I’ve got everything formatted the way I want but I’m having trouble getting to the name and description, any ideas

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" 

<div class="workTile">

                <h3>Test: <xsl:value-of select="Insert List Title" /></h3>
                <div class="workTileContent">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum <xsl:value-of select=" Insert List Description"/></p>
                                <ul>
                                               <xsl:apply-templates />
                                </ul>
                </div>
</div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row">

                <li><a href="{@URL}"><xsl:value-of select="@URL.desc"/></a></li>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to attached a custom header.xsl in your .webpart file then make XSL changes to that.  Then you simply pull in the values from your webparts "slots" and manipulate the data.